# Does php cURL use up RAM or Processor power?

Tags: php, mysql, curl, autoscaling, horizontal-scaling

I currently have a scraper script that simultaneously downloads hundreds of pages a minute using PHP cURL.

I have it set up so that there is one main server and a few remote servers downloading pages using **PHP cURL** and sending the data back using a **REMOTE MYSQL Connection** (the data is then saved in the main server).

I'm trying to optimize and reduce the cost of these servers; so should I be scaling horizontally, or vertically? Should I be looking for more RAM or processor power?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It uses both. To find out "how much" (and if it is even an issue), run some load tests and collect performance and resource usage data. I suspect the bottlenecks will first appear in the network and/or the actual scraping program that uses cURL.

Comment: The bottleneck is network latency! A CPU usually waits millions of cycles until you get a response. Multi-threading is probably the key to success.

Answer (score 1):

You should add NETWORK power. RAM is only needed to host the running process, and CPU is only needed to trigger the network connection.

And please be advised that websites do not like to be overwhelmed with requests. This is usually considered an attack, and they might block you. So play it safe, be a nice net citizen, and don't push as hard as you can. A good spider concept will ask as many DIFFERENT hosts as possible, but only use one or two requests for each single host.

Comment: Hey, would network power be an increased server Uplink? For example upgrading it from 100Mbps to 1 Gbps?